# Using async & await on functions with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, async-await

I have the following code, where I am running into a number of issues, which I assume are related. I cannot use `await` when calling a fucntion due to getting this error `SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and async generators`.

More importantly, my 2nd `ajax` call (the `saveTokenToUser` function) does not seem to be running at all.

What I am trying to do is:

1. onClick of login button - send login details for validation.
2. If successful, also send a token (if provided via the query-string)
   to the server to be saved for this new user.
3. Redirect to a user-based page.
4. if login failed, rest the form and display appropriate messages.

A thank you to T.J. Crowder who has already been very helpful.

A successful login will have a return text in the format of `good|4` (which is why I check for the first 4 chars to be `good`)

CODE:

```
// this code saves the token
var saveTokenToUser = (tokenViaApp) => {
    return $.ajax("/includes/notifications/ajax_save_user_token", {
    data: {
      t: tokenViaApp    
    }, 
  }).done((response) => {
    console.log('Done ', response)
  }).fail(error => {
    console.log('Error ', error)
  })
    .always(response => {
   console.log('always ', response)
  }).then(response => {
    console.log('successfully sent in function');
    localStorage.token_origin = 'app';
  })
} // end function 


// this code verifies login details:  
var checkLogin = async (semail, spass, scaptcha, stokenViaApp) => {
    console.log('Checking login')

    return $.ajax("/users/ajax_login", {
    data: {
        email: semail,
        pass: spass,
        captcha: scaptcha 
        }, 
      }).done((response) => {
        console.log('Done ', response)
      }).fail(error => {
        console.log('Error ', error)
      })
        .always(response => {
       console.log('always ', response)
      }).then(msg => {

        console.log('login response: ' + msg);

        if (msg==='notfound') {
          $("#LoginMessage").html('The user does not exist in the system').addClass("alert alert-danger");
          grecaptcha.reset();
        } else if (msg==='captcha') {
          $("#LoginMessage").html('Are you a robot <i class="fa fa-smile-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>').addClass("alert alert-danger");
        } else if (msg==='bad') {
          $("#LoginMessage").html('The password is incorrect').addClass("alert alert-danger");
          grecaptcha.reset();
        } else if (msg==='pass') {
          $("#LoginMessage").html('Please enter with your password').addClass("alert alert-warning");
          $("#password").removeClass("hidden");
          grecaptcha.reset();
        } else if (msg.substring(0,4)==='good') {
          console.log('token is: ' + stokenViaApp);         


          // login was successful, lets see if a token exists, and then save it: 
          if (stokenViaApp !==''){
            console.log("Starting to save token script ");
            var TokenResponse = saveTokenToUser(stokenViaApp); // tried 'await' here but generated error: SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and async generators
            }

            // all is good, let's redirect: 
            window.location = '/users/default_forwarder.asp';
        }
        return msg;

      })            

} // end function 




$("#submitter").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var email = $("#email").val();
    var pass = $("#entry").val();
    var captcha = $("#g-recaptcha-response").val();
    $("#LoginMessage").html('').removeAttr('class');
    $("#submitter").val('Checking...');

    // check for token: 
    var tokenViaApp = $.urlParam('t')
    if (tokenViaApp == false ) { 
      tokenViaApp = '' 
    }

    // send to login function: 
    var loginResponse = checkLogin(email, pass, captcha, tokenViaApp); // tried 'await' here but generated error: SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and async generators

    $("#submitter").val('Login'); // reset form

});  // on login click
```

THIS IS THE CONSOLE LOG:

```
Checking login 
XHRGET /users/ajax_login?email=...&pass=1234&captcha....
Done  good|2 
always  good|2 
login response: good|2 
token is: 333333 
Starting to save token script 
>> and then a redirect. instead of calling the code to save the token and THEN doing the redirect
```

At no point, is there an ajax call for saving the token, even though I have a token in the URL, and as you can see, the code is seeing it.

So - my question is why is the 2nd function not being successfully called or waited for?

Thank you.

Comment: `var TokenResponse = saveTokenToUser(stokenViaApp);` - this line kicks off an asynchronous `$.ajax` call but you're not awaiting the result, nor do you redirect in a callback. Your `await` isn't working because `.then(msg => { ... })` isn't marked `async`.

Comment: @TylerRoper  thank you. I see i need ti add `async` to that `saveTokenToUser` function header. Could I trouble you to fill in the blanks for me on adding `async` to `.then(msg => { ... })` ?

Comment: You will not need to add `async` to the `saveTokenToUser` function header as it doesn't seem to be using `await`. Try `.then(async msg => { ... })`. Though, mixing callbacks like `.then()`, `.done()`, with `async/await` seems a bit of a smell. Personal preference but I'd rewrite the whole thing to use solely `async/await` as opposed to mixing them.

Comment: @TylerRoper Thank you. I'm really trying to use this as a learning experience to writing efficient and correct code, rather than quick fixes. If you had the time, I would really appreciate being able to see your suggested code for this. TIA!